# Only insert data into a database if it doesn't exist already

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I'm trying to work on a code that allows me to only insert records that have a different ID; if the same ID already exists in the database then the record shouldn't be inserted.

My SQL code is this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into User(UserId,Name,Profession) values(@UserId,@Name,@Profession) WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select UserId From User where UserId = @UserId)", con);
```

But it doesn't work and when I try this, nothing gets added to the database.
How do I correct this query?

Thank you,

Comment: Try using `NOT IN`. Also when inserting with select you need to remove values because your selecting said values.

Comment: Beware that this approach on its own does not prevent duplicities on userId in all cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of :

```
insert into User(UserId,Name,Profession) 
       values(@UserId,@Name,@Profession) 
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select UserId From User where UserId = @UserId)
```

use this query :

```
insert into User(UserId,Name,Profession) 
       select @UserId, @Name, @Profession
       where not exists (Select UserId From User where UserId = @UserId)
```

**Explanation** : AFAIK the insert command can't combine a VALUES and a WHERE clause. But instead of directly supplying the values (using the VALUES clause), you can define a SELECT to indicate the values to insert. And on that SELECT you can now use filters, joins, etc. ..., so you can define there your filter checking that the row doesn't still exists.

Comment: if you describe, WHY, this would be a correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IF NOT EXISTS (Select UserId From User where UserId = @UserId) insert into User(UserId,Name,Profession) values(@UserId,@Name,@Profession) ", con);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is SQL query to achieve the same.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (Select UserId From User where UserId = @UserId
insert into User(UserId,Name,Profession) values(@UserId,@Name,@Profession)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MERGE statement :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

Or using CTE : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql